# Filemaker - Calculate remaining days of leave

Tags: filemaker

I would like to calculate the total number of leave days taken for a specific type of leave to find the balance for that type of leave. An example, I have made three entrees for annual leave on different dates and I would like to know the annual leave balance. 
When creating a new entry and selecting Annual leave for the type of leave, I want a field to show the balance of that type of leave. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9DuP.jpg)

Comment: It would be helpful with a screenshot of your data entry process if you have it.

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot

Comment: We need more context (which tables do you have and how they are related) here. In general, you just need to subtract the sum of days taken from the sum of days allowed (both filtered by the selected type).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started. A calculation field or variable with this calculation will give you the balance for a record id from your person table within a period for a certain type. You need to populate the variables with your search criteria or use fields from your form as input.

```
ExecuteSQL (
"SELECT SUM("Leave Days")
FROM thetable 
WHERE "record primary key field" = ? and "Start Date" >= ? and "End Date" < ? and "Leave Description" = ? "
; "" ; "";$recordid;$startdate;$enddate;$type )
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with SQL

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding a calc field on "Entitled Leave" table summing the used leave days from the "Used Leave" Table, then subtracting them which gave me the balance.

Thanks for the help everyone.